# Quite a milestone, wouldn't you agree?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I hope this one isn't too easy.

> I'm the second of the first, but also the first of the inferior.
>
> I'm the end of belief, but the beginning of faith.
> I'm hidden in a field, but not in a meadow or farmland.
> I'm the start of a name, the last of the unknown.
> I'm found in victory, and in failure.
> I'm found at the start, but not at the beginning.
> I'm found in all questions, who, what, where, when, why, and how.
> You'll see me twice in your eyes, though I am not sight.
> I am done, down, and depleted.
>
> They say there is no 'I' in team, though I am the last member.
> I am the question of the universe, the one most commonly asked.
>
> I'm dangerous if you're allergic to me. My buzz will surely bother you.
> You'll see me if you're surprised. After all, I'm your reaction.
> You'll say me when you've been told an answer you should have known.
> You'll text me when a friend tells you something you don't care about.

What am I trying to say?

Comment: For reference: This was, I think, the first time I managed to solve a puzzle here. So I guess it was easy. Neat nonetheless, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer

> I Finished My Book

I'm the second of the first, but also the first of the inferior.

> I

I'm the end of belief, but the beginning of faith.

> F

I'm hidden in a field, but not in a meadow or farmland.

> I

I'm the start of a name, the last of the unknown.

> N

I'm found in victory, and in failure.

> I

I'm found at the start, but not at the beginning.

> S

I'm found in all questions, who, what, where, when, why, and how.

> H

You'll see me twice in your eyes, though I am not sight.

> E

I am done, down, and depleted.

> D

They say there is no 'I' in team, though I am the last member.

> M

I am the question of the universe, the one most commonly asked.

> Y

I'm dangerous if you're allergic to me. My buzz will surely bother you.

> B

You'll see me if you're surprised. After all, I'm your reaction.

> O

You'll say me when you've been told an answer you should have known.

> O

You'll text me when a friend tells you something you don't care about.

> K

And I think this is quite a milestone :)

Comment: Was it too easy then?

Comment: It was easy but I found it fun to solve! +1 @Joe-You-Know